# Get Last Answer gets unpredictably redefined

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, spyder

I have a strange problem using the "get last answer" command (a.k.a. _) in my interactive python sessions.  I am using the anaconda python distribution with python3.5 and spyder3.2.3 running an ipython6.1.0 console.

The problem is this: for a while, issuing the _ command yields what I expect it to, namely the output of the previous line of code that I entered into the console. But then, without my understanding why, the output of the command _ becomes "frozen" on the output of some previous line of code.  All subsequent calls of _ yield this output.  The only way I have found of "resetting" the behaviour of _ is to kill the interactive session and start anew.

Has someone seen this problem before or knows what I am doing wrong?  How can I prevent this from happening; or is there some way of resetting the behaviour of _ without killing my interactive session?

Thanks for your help.

Adrian

Comment: To be 100% clear: could you copy-paste an example session where this happens into your question?

Comment: I wish my problem were reproducible enough that I could track it to a piece of code! Alas, I haven't found a code snippet that causes _ to be re-set.  Nowhere in my code is there a line of the form _ = <something>.  It's possible I did this inadvertently on my own since I am working in an interactive session after all.  I will keep testing.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that something assigned to `_`; if you have any code that assign to `_` then IPython will not try to have it being the latest output. You ca try `del _` to restore the behavior.

The other possibility is that you are confusing output, with display; If it does not have an `Out[.]` prompt then it's not an output.

It's the same difference than :

```
>>> 1 + 1
2  # this is an output

>>> print(1 + 1)
2  # this is *not* an output
```

You can also use the  `Out` list to access previous outputs; `Out[-1]` should access the last one in case `_` is unavailable because assigned.

Comment: The usual behaviour is that if I type _ = 200 into the interpreter, then call _, I get 200.  But if I do anything else like type foo, interpreter returns 176, then _ returns 176.  So the _ behaviour resets itself automatically.

Comment: In addition, del _ behaves in the same way.  If I type del _ into the interpreter, then call _ , I get NameError: name '_' is not defined.  Now if I do anything else that produces an output, say 176, then _ returns 176. Again, it seems like the _ behaviour resets itself automatically.

Comment: But this usual behaviour of _ changes when my above-described 'problem' occurs. Puzzling!